# toggle search input when mouseenter a div, then hide search input when mouseout

Tags: jquery, forms, toggle, mouseover, mouseout

I'm using a searchform on my website (I can't change the HTML structure as it's the searchform generated by Wordpress).
I have a search icons, and my searchform is hidden.
when mouseenter the search div, I want to toggle my searchform, the searchform stay visible when entering text inside, and when mouseout the divs, I want the searchform to hide, with the same animation as in my Jsfiddle.

I can't find a solution to do it. here is my HTML, I can't change the structure as it's the searchform generated by Wordpress :

```
<div id="search">
<form action="http://www.mmdwc.com" id="searchform" method="get">
<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn"  id="searchsubmit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
<input type="search" id="s" name="s" value="" />
</div>
</form>    
</div>
```

my CSS :

```
body {margin-top:50px;background-color:black;text-align:right}

#search {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

#s {
    border-width: medium medium 1px;
    border-style: none none solid;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color #FFF;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    border-image: none;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: none;
}

#searchsubmit {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #FFF;
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
```

and my jquery :

```
$( "#searchsubmit" ).stop().one( "mouseenter", function() {
    $("#s").animate({width: 'toggle'}, 200);
});
```

and a JSfiddle to see it in action (with the animation) :

http://jsfiddle.net/7hbp57my/

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use [**`mouseenter`**](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) alone or at least not with `toggle` animation.
Using `mouseenter` you also have to set [**`mouseleave`**](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event as the oposite action.

The element on which you should attach event handler is the whole `#search` div, not the button.

[**`.stop()`**](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) isn't required for the button as it doesn't perform any animation (you would rather *stop* input field animation: `$("#s").stop().animate(...)`).

[**`one`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is used to execute an event handler only once. After the event is catched, it's immediately removed from the element and will not perform anymore. You don't want that for sure. If you need an [*event delegation*](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) use [**`on`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

---

```
// cache input element (good practice when you refer to the same object many times):
var s_field = $("#s");

// hover instead of mouseenter:
$( "#search" ).hover(
// on mouse over:
function() {
    // use 'show' instead of toggle:
    s_field.stop().animate({width: 'show'}, 200);
}, 
// on mouse out:
function(){
    // hide input field on "hover out" only when it has no focus:
    if(!s_field.is(":focus")){
        s_field.stop().animate({width: 'hide'}, 200);
    }
});
```

Optionaly, you can hide search element (and clear its *value*) when focus is removed from the field, by binding `focusout` event handler:

```
s_field.focusout(function(){
    // check if mouse pointer is over the element
    // otherwise search field will disapear before button is clicked
    if(!$( "#search" ).is(":hover")){
        s_field.val('').animate({width: 'hide'}, 200);
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t1qxpq6t/)

---

To better understand jQuery's [**`.hover()`**](https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1) handler (a shorthand equivalent for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`):

```
$(element).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut );
```

Additional references:

- [**`.is()`**](http://api.jquery.com/is/);

Comment: thanks for your help, now I understand better how to do this ! thanks a lot, it works perfectly

Comment: Glad I could help :-) There's an improved version : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1qxpq6t/) . I have added `.is(':hover')` condition inside `focusout` handler. Otherwise button click doesn't work